# Get all Angular form controls that have changed from enabled to disabled, or vice versa?

Tags: angular, typescript

**TL,DR**; A [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) is not considered [dirty](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#dirty) when a nested [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) is changed from disabled to enabled, or vice versa.

**Detail**; What is a good way of getting all form controls belonging to a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup), that have changed from *enabled* to *disabled*, or vice versa?

As [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formbuilder-6cjren) shows, the [pristine](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#pristine), [dirty](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#dirty), [touched](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#touched), and [untouched](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#untouched) properties remain unchanged when a control changes from [enabled](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#enable) to [disabled](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable), or vice versa.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  person: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.person = this.fb.group({
      name: this.fb.control(''),
      age: this.fb.control(100),
    });
  }
}
```

The Typescript above defines a single [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) (`person`) with two [FormControls](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) (`name` and `age`).

The HTML below allows the `name` control to be enabled and disabled by clicking a button. Some properties are output too.

```html
<form [formGroup]="person">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
    <button (click)="person.controls['name'].disable()">Disable</button>
    <button (click)="person.controls['name'].enable()">Enable</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Age" formControlName="age">
</form>

<pre>{{person.value | json}}</pre>

disabled: {{ person.disabled }}<br />
pristine: {{ person.pristine }}<br />
dirty: {{ person.dirty }}<br />
touched: {{ person.touched }}<br />
untouched: {{ person.untouched }}<br />
```

[image]

I'd expected it to be easy to detect when a control is:

- enabled (where it was previously disabled)
- disabled (where it was previously enabled)

Unlike the [pristine](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#pristine), [dirty](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#dirty), [touched](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#touched), and [untouched](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#untouched) properties, the enabled and disabled state seems transient.

It seems there is no property of a FormGroup that reflects if child controls have been enabled or disabled away from their original state? The FormGroup remains pristine and untouched.

It has been suggested to use [statusChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#statusChanges). However, this only provides four possible validation status values (VALID, INVALID, PENDING, DISABLED). There is no clear way to map the status to a control and subsequently determine whether is has changed from enabled to disabled or vice versa. I've created [another Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formbuilder-uqisum) demonstrating this.

**EDIT**

I've opened a bug [FormGroup not dirty when a nested FormControl changes from disabled to enabled, or vice versa](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34252).

Comment: isnt there an observable for that ?

Comment: You can always hook into ngDetectChanges and do it manually there.

Comment: @antoniossss - that would require manually tracking the enabled/disabled state of all controls. Doable, but this seems OTT given this approach is not needed for any of the properties cited in my question (IMO).

Comment: have you tried? `person.statusChanges.pipe(map(()=>person.disabled)).subscribe(value => console.log(value));`

Answer (score 3):

You can try to give a shot to listen for control status changes - one of them is `disabled`

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#status

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#statusChanges

EDIT:

There is obvious method for that, but it is called `registerOnDisabledChange`

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#registerOnDisabledChange

Showcase forked form your stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/formbuilder-soydhk

If you need to listen for that on controll level, nothing stands in your way to write aggregating listener.

Comment: `statusChanges` only provides four possible validation status values (`VALID`, `INVALID`, `PENDING`, `DISABLED`). There is no clear way to map the status to a control and subsequently determine whether is has changed from enabled to disabled or vice versa. Here's a Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/formbuilder-uqisum

Comment: use https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#registerOnDisabledChange